# Sphinx search by attribute

Tags: sphinx

Could I search with sphinx only by attributes without query word

config:

```
sql_query = SELECT p.ID as price_id, p.info, p.sort_id, p.made_id, p.category_id, 'prices' as table_id  FROM price AS p
sql_query_info = SELECT * FROM price WHERE ID = $id
sql_attr_uint   = sort_id
```

...

```
min_word_len = 0
min_infix_len = 0
min_prefix_len = 0
enable_star = 1
docinfo = extern
```

code:

```
$search->SetFilter('sort_id',[1,2]);
$search->Query("*","prices");
```

Get 0 results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$search->Query("","prices");
```

If that returns no results, you've got some other logic error.

---

Tangential, why are you 'enable_star' with infix/prefix set to 0? It will have no effect.

Comment: This does not work. I tried it with different length of prefix/infix.

Comment: So there is some other logic error. eg are you using PHP 5.4 and do you definitly have some documents with a sort_id of 1 or 2? (infix/prefix/enable_star have NO bearing at all here, they are for full-text matching, you are trying to get results without a full-text query)

Comment: I have result = array("error"=>"","warning"=>"","status"=>"0",...).

Comment: When I try $search->Query("l*","prices"); I got normal result.

Comment: status=0 means good, the query ran ok. What do you mean by "normal result"?

Comment: I mean, I got some rows in result.

Comment: It shouldn't. Its not a valid sphinx query.

Comment: I found your post [here](http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=93#35823) and SPH_MATCH_FULLSCAN solve my problem. Thanks.